# Strange errors in tests after updating to rspec3

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rspec3

After updating a project to Rspec 3, I get the following strange errors in my tests which I am not able to fix:

```
 undefined method `empty?' for 2:Fixnum
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:251:in `block in missing_keys'
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:251:in `select'
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:251:in `missing_keys'
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:231:in `optimized_helper'
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:220:in `call'
 # /opt/local/lib/ruby2.1/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:10:in `block in <class:UsersController>'
```

`users_controller` line 10 contains a redirect:

```
  redirect_to(user_path(current_user))
```

In each of these cases, `current_user` is a mocked User object created using `mock_model(User, login: User.make_token)` and has the ID value quoted in the error message (before ":Fixnum").

This happens with every redirect that contains an *object*. Examples:

```
redirect_to current_user
redirect_to user_path(current_user)
redirect_to url_for([:admin, current_user, :edit])
```

If I use the object's ID as in `redirect_to user_path(current_user.id))`, the error does not occur. However, then e.g. `url_for` breaks as well, since I cannot use `url_for([@parent.id, @object.id, :edit])` (the objects cannot be derived from their IDs only but are needed for the path).

This only happens when using mocked objects with RSpec 3 and Rails 4.2.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated since this makes a lot of tests fail right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rspec 3 extracted mocks support](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/) into the [rspec-activemodel-mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-activemodel-mocks) gem, so you might need to add `rspec-activemodel-mocks` to your Gemfile in order for the route helpers to behave as expected in your specs.

Comment: Thanks. I have that gem already (otherwise no routes would work at all), though. Error still occurs... :(

Comment: Have you tried adding `:to_param` to your  `mock_model` (like `mock_model(User, login: User.make_token, to_param: 7)`)?  Maybe rails is having trouble creating parameters out of the mock model because expected instance methods haven't been stubbed.

Comment: Actually, it was the other way around. Some of my initialization sequences included a "to_param: 1" block that was included in all `mock_model` calls. This pointed me to the right direction. I removed it. Now I'm getting useful test failures again (and need to find out why it was added in the first place ...). Thanks!